# Automorphisms of algebraically closed fields without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, fields, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-groups

In the paper *Algebraische Konsequenzen des Determiniertheits-Axioms* (U. Felgner – K. Schulz, Arch. Math. (Basel) 42 (1984), pp. 557–563), the authors show that in models of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without the Axiom of Choice, but *with* the Axiom of Determinacy, one can show that the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ only has one nontrivial automorphism (being complex conjugation).

Can the same be said about *any* algebraically closed field in characteristic $0$ (and if so, why, or where can I found a clear reference)?

**EDIT**: in view of the answer and comments below, I want to add two more nuanced questions.

- Suppose we work in Zermelo-Fraenkel without Choice. Is it consistent
  to say that for every field $k$ in characteristic $0$, there exists
  and algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$ for which the
  automorphism group has *size at most $2$*?
- Same setting. Is it consistent to say that every uncountable
  algebraically closed field has at most $2$ automorphisms?

Answer (score 8):

Läuchli constructed an algebraic closure of the rationals which does not have any non-identity automorphisms.

> *Läuchli, H.*, [**Auswahlaxiom in der Algebra**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02566957), Comment. Math. Helv. 37, 1-18 (1962). [ZBL0108.01002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0108.01002).

This field was studied in more details by Hodges in the paper

> *Hodges, Wilfrid*, [**Lauchli’s algebraic closure of Q**](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100052282), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 79, 289-297 (1976). [ZBL0324.02058](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0324.02058).

Comment: Yes, but the standard construction of algebraic closure of Q gives, in ZF, a well-ordered (countable) algebraically closed field, which has all the usual $2^\omega$ automorphisms. Hence irrespective of any further examples like this, the answer to the original question is NO.

Comment: I don't have access to those articles, but is the issue that representing a complex number in the algebraic closure as 'a+bi' with a, b real requires choice?

Comment: @asafkaragila: and what if I change my question into: "at most one nontrivial automorphism" ?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: if I am not mistaken, you need AC for this ?

Comment: @THC: No, Emil is correct. AC is only needed to prove that all algebraic closures of the rationals are isomorphic. But there is always a countable one. Indeed, the one you get inside $\Bbb C$ itself is countable.

Comment: @Will: Well, it's about representing an element of the algebraic closure as a complex number to begin with. If $x^5-1$ has four irrational roots, which witch watch which watch? And now apply that to infinitely many polynomials, and we get that. This is really more about choice from families of finite sets, which is why linear orders are generally enough to get a modicum of canonicity here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I added two additional variations on my questions, in the hope they make more sense?

Comment: The answer to the additional questions is still NO. 1. You already know that there exists an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$ that has a lot of automorphisms. Now, the unique algebraic closure of $k$ is $k$ itself. 2. Take an uncountable well-orderable field such as $\mathbb Q(\{X_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\})$. Such a field has, provably in ZF, a well-orderable algebraic closure, and this will again have lots of automorphisms.

Comment: @THC: The problem here is that the failure of choice does not preclude very large well-orderable objects, as Emil points out. You can get some kind of approximation to this fact in the following sense. Every field (of any characteristics!) has an extension which has an algebraic closure with no automorphisms. This can be found in my paper "Iterated failures of choice".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: that's a great result ! Thank you for the reference (I will certainly use it) !!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Dear Asaf, I browsed through your paper (actually a preprint -- is it already published ?), but cannot seem to find the result your are referring to. I guess it is implicitly contained in section 5 ?